# Selenium to log on to website using driver elements

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

Below I have attached the html code for the username and password:

USERNAME:

```html
<input class="form-control input-sm snl-widgets-input-text snl-selectable action" data-part="input" data-bind="snlEnable: enable,value: value,valueUpdate: valueUpdate,visible: visible,css: { 'tags': enableTagsInput, 'clear': enableClear, 'search': enableSearch, 'action': externalActionVisible, 'pseudoTags': enablePseudoTags },hasFocus: hasFocus,attr: { type: type, name: name, placeholder: placeholder, maxlength: maxlength }" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email address" maxlength="524288">
```

PASSWORD:

```html
<input class="form-control input-sm snl-widgets-input-text snl-selectable action" data-part="input" data-bind="snlEnable: enable,value: value,valueUpdate: valueUpdate,visible: visible,css: { 'tags': enableTagsInput, 'clear': enableClear, 'search': enableSearch, 'action': externalActionVisible, 'pseudoTags': enablePseudoTags },hasFocus: hasFocus,attr: { type: type, name: name, placeholder: placeholder, maxlength: maxlength }" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="524288">
```

I am using python 3.7.

I have an "unable to located element" error when using the following xpaths that were provided when right clicking and asking for xpath:

```html
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=applicationHost]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[11]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=applicationHost]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[11]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input")
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Rather than asking which one to try, try one... try them all and see what happens. Read a guide on which locators are better supported, better performing, etc. There are a TON of guides out there already.

Comment: I have attempted the following element locators: css_selector, name, id, class and xpath. For all of those I received an error that no such element existed. Except for xpath, where I attempted the WebDriverWait method and received a TimeoutException error.

Comment: Then you need to update your question with what you have tried and the results of EACH... specifying the exact error message.

Comment: How are `html code for the button` and `code for username element` related?

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest explicitly waiting for the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url="http://www.example.com"#your url here
driver.get(url)
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//img[starts-with(@id,'removeImage_')]')))
#or '//img[contains(@id,'removeImage_')]'
element.click()
```

Comment: I attempted this and received the TimeoutException error.

Comment: This is the URL for the login page where i am struggling to enter my username and password: https://platform.spgi.spglobal.com/web/client?auth=inherit&bmctx=1305DE25F219961752D2443C2563A499&contextType=external&username=string&enablePersistentLogin=true&OverrideRetryLimit=0&SwitchGetToPostLimit=50000&contextValue=%2Foam&password=secure_string&challenge_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplatform.spgi.spglobal.com%2Fweb%2Fclient%3Fauth%3Dinherit&request_id=-6136312430842175674&authn_try_count=0&locale=en_US&resource_url=https%253A%252F%252Fplatform.mi.spglobal.com%252Finteractivex%252Fdefault.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With the snippet you posted, I can suggest you:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.ID, "removeImage_E61858CD-F1F9-42BD-8848-8CB6B42ED2FE")
```

Another way could be with the xPath. One of the many ways you can use to retrieve the xPath, is to open it in a browser (i.e. firefox), right click the element, inspect(Q), Copy, xPath and you have the xpath to use:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your[4]/xPath/to[2]/element')
```

If you want to click the element, add click() at the end:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "removeImage_E61858CD-F1F9-42BD-8848-8CB6B42ED2FE").click().
```

I can't suggest you a good tutorial, but here you can find a [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Most times I come across elements like these with a GUID/UUID, they are dynamically generated.  Which means the next time it might not be `driver.find_element(By.ID, "removeImage_E61858CD-F1F9-42BD-8848-8CB6B42ED2FE")` anymore.  The GUID/UUID might change.  I'd suggest use the `By.XPATH` method with a contain `removeImage_` clause.

Comment: I just realized I will not be able to tell if this works until I enter my username and password to log on. After copying the XPATH by doing a right click on the HTML code for the username and password input boxes, it stated that there was no such element in my code. Could you help me determine the element for the code that i added (to the original post)

Answer (score 0):

you can locate the elements by name...

```
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
```

Comment: I receive a no such element exception for this. I thought this was one of the solution as well.